# sns.catplot, closing the gap between bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

This is the plot I get when I run this code
Is there any way I can reduce the gap between those two bars but not completely touching each other??

```
sns.catplot(x = "case", kind = "count", data = df, alpha=0.8, palette = my_pal, hue="class")
plt.ylabel("Count", size=12)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: The gap between the bars is sufficient for two additional bars, one for each hue value. The count (y) is 0 for x=0 and hue = 'green.' Similarly, the count is 0 for x=1 and hue = 'Negative.' If these two values were non-zero, would you want the space to appear as it is?

Comment: @BalooRM yes I want to remove the spaces saved for those cases if two values were non-zero.

Comment: @JohanC yes I am

Comment: This may come down to aesthetics for data visualization, but varying the position relative to the label on the x-axis could be confusing. Will those zero values always be zero? If your intent is to label the green and Negative groups with different colors, you might look at a stacked column graph, instead.

Comment: Here's a stacked barplot example. https://randyzwitch.com/creating-stacked-bar-chart-seaborn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the columns 'case' and 'class' contain the same information, just with a different name. Everywhere where case is 1, class is Negative, and vice versa.

If you are both using `x` and `hue`, seaborn makes place for 4 columns:

- case 1, class 'Negative'
- case 1, class 'green'
- case 2, class 'Negative'
- case 2, class 'green'

Two of the four columns stay empty:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'case': np.concatenate([np.repeat([1], 3700), np.repeat([2], 1200)]),
                   'class': np.concatenate([np.repeat(['Negative'], 3700), np.repeat(['green'], 1200)])})

g = sns.catplot(x="case",
                hue='class',
                palette='Blues',
                data=df,
                kind="count")
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

In that case, a more adequate plot would be to leave out `hue` and directly use the class as `x`:

```py
g = sns.catplot(x='class',
                palette='Blues',
                data=df,
                kind='count')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot without hue]

PS: To get a similar legend as in the first plot, the xticks and xlabel could be used.  Note that a seaborn `catplot` is meant to create a complete grid of subplots. `g.axes[0][0]` grabs the `ax` of the first subplot.

```
plt.legend(g.axes[0][0].patches,
           [l.get_text() for l in g.axes[0][0].get_xticklabels()],
           title= g.axes[0][0].get_xlabel())
g.axes[0][0].set_xticks([])  # remove the xticks (now in legend)
g.axes[0][0].set_xlabel('')  # remove the xlabel (now title of legend)
```

Comment: thank you so much, but do you know how to add the same legend as the first plot on the second plot??

Comment: I added a way to add a legend (and remove the xticks and xlabel)